# How to make the function which is used inside a loop work synchronously?

Tags: node.js

I'am trying to call onScan2 function which is inside a onScan function , but the onScan2 function gets processed at the last. So how can i make my code work in the synchronous manner ,so the when it comes inside the onScan , then first it processes the onScan2 fully and later continue processing onScan function.

```
function onScan(err,data){

                if(err){
                    console.log("Unable to scan");

                }
                else{
                    let ps=[];
                    data.Items.forEach(function(data) {
                        ps.push(data);
                    });
                    if(ps.length==0)
                    {
                        console.log("unable to add in ps");
                    }
                    else
                    {


                       for(var i=0, len=ps.length;i<len; i++){
                            let routForm= ps[i].a+"-"+ps[i].b;


                           var c={
                                TableName : q,
                                FilterExpression: "#xe=:xe",
                                ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#xe': 'xe'  },
                                ExpressionAttributeValues: {':xe': routForm }
                            };

                            var data2=documentClient.scan(c,onScan2);

                            ps[i]dq= dq;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            function onScan2(err,data){
                                    if(err)                                       

                                    else{

                                    return data;
                                    }
                            }
```

Comment: promises or async/await might be of help

Comment: i know about using the promises or async/await , but unable to implement it or the same . Can you help me with that?